# c# Unable to solve clipboard error even

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I am trying to just get information from the clipboard in a simple bit of code. I have done lots of searching but none of the posts have solved my issue. I have ensured that I am using System.Windows.Forms; 
below is the code. Am I missing something else?

//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {



        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(txtCopy.Text);
            txtPaste.Text = Clipboard.GetText();

        }
    }
}
```

Below are the errors when I run the code

```
Error(s):
(22:13) The name 'Clipboard' does not exist in the current context
(22:31) The name 'txtCopy' does not exist in the current context
(23:13) The name 'txtPaste' does not exist in the current context
(23:29) The name 'Clipboard' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: The errors mean exactly what they say.  Where are any of those objects defined?

Comment: @DStanley `Clipboard` is in the [`System.Windows.Forms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace, OP must not be showing us the code that is giving the error. I only get that `txtCopy` and `txtPaste` do not exist for his code. edit: also I had to add reference to forms and add the `[STAThread]` attribute to this console application to make OP's code work.. he tried to make a "minimal" question I think and didn't do a very good job.

Comment: @Quantic You're right.  I was looking at the WPF clipboard.  I suspect the OP copy and pasted Winform code into a console app.

Answer (score 0):

You have change the Program.main() method of windows Form application, and you are not launching any Form from it. There should be something like this inside that method.

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
```

This is the method that is call when you run the program, and is not initializing any Form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `System.Windows.Forms` at the start of your file in order to resolve the Clipboard missing error. The MSDN page for it is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to look.

You also never define your `txtCopy` and `txtPaste` variables so these are showing as missing references too.

I'm assuming `txtCopy` and `txtPaste` are some kind of input within a form? If this is the cast you're not initialising your form as you never create one, so nothing will be generated. That being said even if you add the initialisation you won't be able to access the controls from within the main method as the objects will be out of scope as they're contained in the Form class itself.

Assuming you are using a VS basic template you should structure your code as follows to achieve your functionality.

Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    /* Once you call the InitializeComnents method you will be able to access controls added in design view */
    Clipboard.SetText(txtCopy.Text);
    txtPaste.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

Remember your using statements too!